# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un String con el nombre de la clase hija desde una clase padre (herencia)?

Tags: java

Si tengo una clase padre, por ejemplo `Operacion`, y tengo dos clases hijas, por ejemplo `Suma` y `Resta`, ¿cómo puedo obtener el nombre en formato `String` para que me devuelva "Suma" o "Resta" de las clases hijas desde la clase padre `Operacion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre se debe devolver el nombre de la clase sin más, entonces puedes utilizar reflection. Crea un método en la clase padre así

```
public String nombre() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

Esto evita la necesitad de sobreescribir en las clases hijas. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
Operacion operacion = new Operacion();
Operacion suma = new Suma();
Operacion resta = new Resta();
System.out.println(operacion.getNombre());
System.out.println(suma.getNombre());
System.out.println(resta.getNombre());
```

En caso que utilices Java 8, puedes aumentar esta funcionalidad de una mejor manera vía interfaces de la siguiente forma:

```
public interface BrindaNombreSimple {
    default String getNombre() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

```
public class Operacion implements BrindaNombreSimple {
    //definición de la clase...
    //no necesitas definir el método getNombre puesto que ya está en la interfaz
}
```

Esto permite que otras clases puedan tener esta misma funcionalidad sin necesidad de heredar de la clase `Operacion`.

Answer (score 1):

O simplemente con el "super.toString()" puedes heredar de la clase padre los metodos toString a los cuales dentro de la clase hija puedes modificarlos a tu manera.Siempre claro que tengas extendidas e implementadas las clases con los cuales quieres hacer la herencia. No te puedo extender más porque no se si es lo que pides exactamente.
Saludos compañero

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estoy por si no sabes muy bien como funciona el "super" te lo he hecho para que lo entiendas y te facilite las cosas (es un ejemplo un poco tonto)

```
public class OperacionImpl {

    public String toString(){
        return "Suma";

    }
    public String toString1(){
        return "Resta";
    }
}

public class SumaResta extends OperacionImpl {

    public String toString(){
        return  super.toString() +" ó " +  super.toString1();
    }
}


public class Testeo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SumaResta sumrest = new SumaResta();
        sumrest.toString();
        System.out.println(sumrest);
    }

}
//el cual imprime por pantalla "Suma ó Resta"
```

Saludos y espero haberte ayudado aunque ya sepas la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobrescribir el metodo toString()

```
public class Suma  extends Operacion{    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Suma";
    }   
}
```

Uso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Operacion operacion = new Suma();

    System.out.println(operacion.toString());
}
```

Output:

> Suma

---

**O** puedes crear un metodo en la clase operación y sebreescribirlo en sus hijos

```
public class Operacion {    
    public String getNombre(){
        return "Operacion";     
    }
}
```

Clase hija:

```
public class Suma  extends Operacion{

    @Override
    public String getNombre() {

        return "Suma";
    }
.....
}
```

Uso:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Operacion operacion = new Suma();

    System.out.println(operacion.getNombre());
}
```

Output:

> Suma

El secreto es la anotación [@Override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pedazo de respuesta. Lo he conseguido hace un momento y antes de leer tu comentario! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que lo que tu necesitas es aplicar el concepto de **Polimorfismo** en Java. Esto es basicamente la definición de un método de manera general, que luego una determinada clase se encargara de dar funcionalidad de forma concreta.

En java podemos aplicar este concepto mediante el uso de ***interfaces*** o de ***clase abstracta***.

¿Cuando deberia usar interfaces o clases abstractas?, pues en mi opinión si quieres tener implementados ciertos métodos de forma común para un jerarquia de clases deberías usar una **clase abstracta**, si no necesitas esos métodos comunes a la jerarquia sería mejor hacerlo con **interfaces**, vamos al código, primero con una clase abstracta:

```
public abstract class Operation {
  public boolean isArithmeticOperation() {
    return true;
  }

  public abstract String getName();

}
```

Para todas las clases que extienden la jerarquia se ofrece ya un método implementado, y se deja otro método para que sea implementado por cada clase:

```
public class Suma extends Operation {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "suma";
  }
}

public class Resta extends Operation {
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "resta";
  }
}
```

La clase Concatenacion no es una operación aritmetica, así que además sobre escribe el método común:

```
public class Concatenacion extends Operation {
  @Override
  public boolean isArithmeticOperation() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "concatenacion";
  }

}
```

Aqui te paso test para comprobar que no te miento:

```
@Test
public void testIsArithmeticOperation() {
  List<Operation> listOperation=new ArrayList<Operation>(
            Arrays.asList(new Suma(),new Resta(),new Concatenacion(),new Resta()
    ));

  assertThat(listOperation.get(0).isArithmeticOperation(),is(true));
  assertThat(listOperation.get(1).isArithmeticOperation(),is(true));
  assertThat(listOperation.get(2).isArithmeticOperation(),is(false));
  assertThat(listOperation.get(3).isArithmeticOperation(),is(true));
}

@Test
public void testGetName() {
  List<Operation> listOperation=new ArrayList<Operation>(
            Arrays.asList(new Suma(),new Resta(),new Concatenacion(),new Resta()
    ));

  assertThat(listOperation.get(0).getName(),is(equalTo("suma")));
  assertThat(listOperation.get(1).getName(),is(equalTo("resta")));
  assertThat(listOperation.get(2).getName(),is(equalTo("concatenacion")));
  assertThat(listOperation.get(3).getName(),is(equalTo("resta")));
}
```

Y si hubieramos utilizado un interface, como sería el código.... creamos el interface que necesitamos:

```
public interface Operation {
  public String getName();
}
```

Y la clase base para la jerarquia pasaria a ser asi:

```
public abstract class AbstractOperation implements Operation {
  public boolean isArithmeticOperation() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Casualmente ;) , el test funciona perfectamente despues de esta refactorización del código sin cambio alguno..... la orientación a objetos es algo muy potente y maravilloso.

Answer (score 0):

getClass().getSimpleName() // Te muestra el nombre de la clase solamente

getClass().getName() // Te muestra el nombre del package+clase